# Django URLs configuration debugging?

Tags: python, django, url, debugging

What's the best method to debug Django's url configurations? Sometime it just throw out a Unhandled Exception without any hints if there is an error in urls.py

Sometimes it throws out errors like "unbalanced parenthesis" but I still dont know which line in urls.py caused the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For underlying application errors, I sometimes find it helpful to toggle the value of `TEMPLATE_DEBUG` in `settings.py` ([django docs here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-debug)). Often this gives me the backtrace I need to spot syntax errors outside the template, or other bone-headed code that I might have botched.

If that fails, try importing your view module from the django shell:

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from myapp_that_causes_problems import views
```

If there's truly a syntax error, this will bomb in the import and expose the offending line immediately.

Answer (score 0):

for unbalanced parenthises and other such syntax errors, I find it useful to run pylint on the file. If you use vim, there is a plugin to automatically do this upon save https://github.com/orenhe/pylint.vim