# Is there a way to debug Django urls?

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a problem with Django urls that I cannot get to the bottom of. I have tried the recommendations given in the [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878096/django-urls-configuration-debugging), but they don't help.

**<project>/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('duo/', include('duo.urls')),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
]
```

**duo/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('', include('users.urls')),
    ...
]
```

**users/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.SelectPartner.as_view(), name='select-partner'),
    ...
]
```

when I use the url *http://192.168.1.138:8000/duo/* I get taken to the page http://192.168.1.138:8000/accounts/login/?next=/duo/ which does not exist.

I cannot think what is going on here because the word *accounts* does not exist anywhere in the project

Is there some tool that I can use to find out what is happening?

Comment: Can you share your main urls.py?

Comment: It's there in <project>/urls.py

Comment: Where is login url?

Comment: See the answer and my comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have login required somewhere which sends you to default [login page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) location

If you are going to use default  [authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) you can add these views up

Comment: This was the offending code `@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')`

Comment: yes as you are using class based views, but that is same decorator

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to use the app in URL and then further parameters. Then it will work by default authentication is available in URL if you are going to use authentication

Answer (score 0):

For a general way to debug Django URLs, you can insert a breakpoint into [django/urls/resolvers.py. in URLResolver.resolve()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/urls/resolvers.py#L677).  I usually make it an IDE conditional breakpoint, so that execution doesn't stop on every single HTTP request and URL pattern.  Just inside the `for pattern in self.url_patterns:` loop I add a conditional breakpoint for a unique URL path, unique pattern-

```
# if your IDE doesn't do conditional breakpoints, just add an if-
if 'unique_path_part' in path and 'unique_url_pattern' in str(self) and 'more_unique_stuff' in str(pattern):
    # add breakpoint here, like [pudb](https://pypi.org/project/pudb/)
    # e.g. import pudb; pu.db
```

Django is silent about why a URL did not match any pattern, but that's not necessarily its fault.  Sometimes you have to freeze time with a breakpoint to understand what is incorrect in either URL or pattern.

I acknowledge that this is janky. But sometimes it's very useful, especially for developers new to Django, or those who hit a pattern problem (like a regex that's slightly off, in my case)